# How to let a property change event fire when its sub-property changes?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a class AdvanceBasicEffect, it has a property SpecularColor which is object of class AdvanceVector3 class, so when i bind specularColor.X property, property change event fires but only in AdvanceVector3 class not in AdvanceBasicEffect.

See the code you will figure out :

```
public partial class Lights : UserControl
{
    public Lights()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
        basicEffect = new AdvanceBasicEffect();
    }

    public AdvanceBasicEffect basicEffect { get; set; }
}

public class AdvanceBasicEffect : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public AdvanceBasicEffect()
    {
        SpecularColor = new AdvanceVector3();
        basicEffect = ((bathroom)CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.Components.First()).basicEffect;
    }

    BasicEffect basicEffect;

    AdvanceVector3 _SpecularColor;
    public AdvanceVector3 SpecularColor 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _SpecularColor;
        }
        set
        {
            //Line 1 : event not occuring 

            _SpecularColor = value;
            if(basicEffect!=null)
             basicEffect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = new Vector3(_SpecularColor.X, _SpecularColor.Y, _SpecularColor.Z);
            valueChanged("SpecularColor");

        }
    }

    private void valueChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
            CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.models[0].SetMeshEffect("Archinteriors7_10_80", basicEffect, false);
            CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.models[0].SetMeshEffect("Archinteriors7_10_111", basicEffect, false);
            CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.models[0].SetMeshEffect("Archinteriors7_10_112", basicEffect, false);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}



public class AdvanceVector3 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    float _X;
    public float X
    {
        get
        {
            return _X;
        }
        set
        {
            _X = value;
            valueChanged("X");
        }
    }

    float _Y;
    public float Y
    {
        get
        {
            return _Y;
        }
        set
        {
            _Y = value;
            valueChanged("Y");
        }
    }

    float _Z;
    public float Z
    {
        get
        {
            return _Z;
        }
        set
        {
            _Z = value;
            valueChanged("Z");
        }
    }

    private void valueChanged(string p)
    {
        //line 2 :Event Occuring 
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
            //CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.models[0].SetMeshEffect("Archinteriors7_10_80", basicEffect, false);
            //CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.models[0].SetMeshEffect("Archinteriors7_10_111", basicEffect, false);
            //CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.models[0].SetMeshEffect("Archinteriors7_10_112", basicEffect, false);
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

At comment "Line 1" event is occurring whereas on "Line 2" event occur, so my question is when the sub property changes then why is the parent property change not occuring. I can not define X,Y,Z in same class as i have many properties which are going to need AdvanceVector3 class

Binding code is as follows :

```
  <Slider ToolTip="SpecularColorX" Minimum="-1" Maximum="1" Value="{Binding basicEffect.SpecularColor.X}" />
        <Slider ToolTip="SpecularColorY" Minimum="-1" Maximum="1" Value="{Binding basicEffect.SpecularColor.Y}" />
        <Slider ToolTip="SpecularColorZ" Minimum="-1" Maximum="1" Value="{Binding basicEffect.SpecularColor.Z}" />
```

Comment: Praent property change should be occuring. Are you sure you are changing `SpecularColor` and not the `_SpecularColor` field in your code? Please show us how the X/Y/Z change happens

Comment: I have shown Binding code, (X,Y,Z) changes when i move slider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I follow your question correctly, I think your misunderstanding what INPC means and when it triggers.

If you say have

```
Class ParentClass : INotifyPropertyChanged {

  public ChildClass SomeObject {
    get { ... }
    set { ... valueChanged("SomeObject"); }
  }

  ...

}
```

and

```
Class ChildClass : INotifyPropertyChanged {

  public string SomeString {
    get { ... }
    set { ... valueChanged("SomeString"); }
  }

  ...

}
```

Now if you either from xaml or code-behind change `SomeString` in an object of `ParentClass`

```
var parentObject = new ParentClass {SomeObject = new ChildClass {SomeString = "Hi"}};

// will trigger property changed in ChildClass for SomeString property
// however it will not trigger a PropertyChanged in ParentClass for SomeObject
parentObject.SomeObject.SomeString = "New String"

// will trigger property changed in ParentClass for SomeObject property
parentObject.SomeObject = new ChildClass();
```

Your xaml bindings work fine since you bind directly to the properties and as and when they change your View is updated accordingly.

If you are wanting to "observe" any changes to `SomeString` from inside the `ParentClass`, then you need to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of `ChildClass.SomeString`

so say `ParentClass` can be updated to

```
  public ChildClass SomeObject {
    get { ... }
    set { 
       if (value == _someObject)
         return;

       _someObject.PropertyChanged -= ChildObjectValueChanged;
       _someObject = value;
       _someObject.PropertyChanged += ChildObjectValueChanged;

       valueChanged("SomeObject"); }
  }

  private void ChildObjectValueChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
    if (args.PropertyName == "SomeString")
      // Child Object property "SomeString" has changed. Do what you need here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for understanding my Problem, and this is solves my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your setter never gets called. Wpf itself calls `PropertyChagned` on `INotifyPropertyChanged` imlplementations. What you should do is to subsribe to changed event yourself in your `AdvancedBasicEffect` class constructor instead of setting mesh effect in `valueChanged` method:

```
public AdvanceBasicEffect()
{
    SpecularColor = new AdvanceVector3();
    basicEffect = ((bathroom)CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.Components.First()).basicEffect;

    SpecularColor.PropertyChanged += (o,e) => 
    {
        CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.models[0].SetMeshEffect("Archinteriors7_10_80", basicEffect, false);
        CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.models[0].SetMeshEffect("Archinteriors7_10_111", basicEffect, false);
        CurrentWindowHandle.currentGame.models[0].SetMeshEffect("Archinteriors7_10_112", basicEffect, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: NO this does not work, because when slider moves only property of AdvanceVector3 class changes, and AdvanceBasicEffect class remains unaffected.

Comment: @Shivam cv Did you try it with subsribing to `SpecularColor.PropertyChanged` then? I imagine both should work...

Comment: Yes, its the same thing but not working. But if i create another property, lets take "SpecularPower" of int type and bind it , then it works because slider is changing specularPower property itself, but here the case is different